Javascript file not loading in php page template
I have some js files that are not loading. The code works sound if I use <script> //js code </script> in the page template but not if I try and load the script from a separate file.
Here is the Website Page
here is page template: simsgen.php
`
    <?php include 'dlc_packs.php'; ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Dynamically Generated Labels</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
     <script  src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/challengeGenerator.js'; ?>">   </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/checkbox-interactions.js'; ?>"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h2>Filters</h2>

        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectAllPacks"> Select All
        </label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectExpansionPacks" class="dlc-pack"> Select All Expansion Packs 
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectGamePacks" class="dlc-pack"> Select All Game Packs 
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectStuffPacks" class="dlc-pack"> Select All Stuff Packs 
        </label>

        <br>
        <div class="checkbox-container flex">
            <?php foreach ($dlcPacks as $label => $packs): ?>
                <h3><?= $label ?></h3>
                <?php foreach ($packs as $pack): ?>
                    
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="dlc-pack" value="<?= $pack ?>"> <?= $pack ?>
                    </label>
                
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>

        <h3> Generate Build or Game Play</h3>
        <label for="selectBuildChallenge">
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectBuildChallenge" name="challengeType"> Build Challenge
        </label>
        <label for="selectGameChallenge">
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectGameChallenge" name="challengeType"> Game Challenge
        </label>

Generate Sim Build
       <div id="sim-build">   
       

 </div>
    </body>
    </html>

</main><!-- #main -->

`
here is checkbox-interactions.js
`$(document).ready(function() {
// Select All Checkbox Functionality
$("#selectAllPacks").click(function() {
$(".dlc-pack").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
// Individual Checkbox Functionality
$(".dlc-pack").click(function() {
    if (!$(this).prop('checked')) {
        $("#selectAllPacks").prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        var allChecked = true;
        $(".dlc-pack").each(function() {
            if (!$(this).prop('checked')) {
                allChecked = false;
                return false; // Break out of loop
            }
        });
        $("#selectAllPacks").prop('checked', allChecked);
    }
});

});
`
here is the generator code
           function generateSimBuild() {
        // Check if at least one challenge type is selected
        var buildChallengeSelected = document.getElementById('selectBuildChallenge').checked;
        var gameChallengeSelected = document.getElementById('selectGameChallenge').checked;
    
        if (!buildChallengeSelected && !gameChallengeSelected) {
            // Display a warning if no challenge type is selected
            document.getElementById('sim-build').innerHTML = '<p>Please select at least one challenge type.</p>';
            return;
        }
    
        const time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 46) + 12;
        var kind = ["Art Studio", "Museum", "Castle", "Tudor-style House", "Georgian House", "Town House", "Cottage", "Mansion", "Shack", "Graveyard", "swimming pool", "farm"];
    
        // Check DLC 
        var getFamousChecked = document.getElementById("getFamousPack").checked;
        var dineOutChecked = document.getElementById("dineOutPack").checked;
        var getToWorkChecked = document.getElementById("getToWorkPack").checked;
        var moschinoChecked = document.getElementById("moschinoPack").checked;
        var growingTogetherChecked = document.getElementById("growingTogetherPack").checked;
        var horseRanchChecked = document.getElementById("horseRanchPack").checked;
    
        // Add lot style to kind
        if (getFamousChecked || getToWorkChecked) {
            kind.push("Photography Studio");
            kind.push("Film Studio");
        }
        if (dineOutChecked) {
            kind.push("Restaurant");
        }
        if (getToWorkChecked) {
            kind.push("Bakery");
            kind.push("Retail Store");
            kind.push("Café");
        }
        if (growingTogetherChecked){
            kind.push("Thrift Tea Store")
        }
        if (horseRanchChecked) {
            kind.push("Horse Ranch")
        }
    
        var selectedKind = kind[Math.floor(Math.random() * kind.length)];
    
        var buildPrefix = selectedKind.charAt(0).match(/[aeiouAEIOU]/) ? "An" : "A";
    
        var buildChallenges = [
            "Shell Challenge",
            "Different Sized Rooms",
            "Each Room A Certain Budget",
            "Each Room A Different Pack",
            "Build " + buildPrefix + " " + selectedKind,
            "Renovate an EA Build",
            "Each Room A Specific Colour",
            "Build in " + time + " Minutes",
            "Jigsaw Challenge",
            "No Mistakes"
        ];
        var gameChallenges = [
            "Legacy Challenge",
            "Barbie Challenge"
        ];
    
        var challenges = [];
    
        // Merge buildChallenges and gameChallenges arrays if both checkboxes are ticked
        if (buildChallengeSelected && gameChallengeSelected) {
            challenges = buildChallenges.concat(gameChallenges);
        } else {
            // Select the appropriate array based on the selected checkboxes
            challenges = buildChallengeSelected ? buildChallenges : gameChallenges;
        }
    
        var selectedPacksCount = document.querySelectorAll('.dlc-pack:checked').length;
    
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * challenges.length);
        var randomChallenge = challenges[randomIndex];
    
        // Check if the Certain Pack challenge should be included
        if (randomChallenge === "Each Room A Different Pack" && selectedPacksCount <= 6) {
            // Skip generating the Certain Pack challenge if less than 6 DLC packs are selected
            randomChallenge = challenges[Math.floor(Math.random() * (challenges.length - 1))];
        }
    
        // Display the generated challenge name as an <h2> element
        document.getElementById('sim-build').innerHTML = '<h2>' + randomChallenge + '</h2>';
    
        // Generate mini-generator based on the selected challenge
        var miniGeneratorOutput = '';
        switch (randomChallenge) {
            case 'Each Room A Certain Budget':
                miniGeneratorOutput = generateCertainBudget();
                break;
            case 'Each Room A Specific Colour':
                miniGeneratorOutput = generateCertainColour();
                break;
            case 'Shell Challenge':
                miniGeneratorOutput = "This is a simple challenge. Grab a shell from the gallery. LittleSimsie will have some that you can use, along with some other players. A shell is just the shape/structure of a build with no decoration or furniture. Turn the shell into something. You cannot change the existing walls but you can add new walls inside (not outside).  and you can decorate and furnish however you want, including the roof."
                break;
            case 'Different Sized Rooms':
                miniGeneratorOutput = "Build a functional lot that has each room a different size, starting from 1 by 1 all the way to 8 by 8. The lot has to be functional and all rooms also have to be accessable either by a door or an archway."
                break;
            case 'Renovate an EA Build':
                miniGeneratorOutput = "Redo a build made by EA. You cannot change the outside walls unless building an extension. This means you can add an entirely new room onto an exteria but cannot knock down an exteria wall. You can change the inside walls. Lot type must be the same, so if it is a tiny residental, it must stay a tiny residental."
                break;
            case 'Build in ' + time + ' Minutes':
                miniGeneratorOutput = timedHouseChallenge();
                break;
            case 'Build ' + buildPrefix + " " + selectedKind:
                miniGeneratorOutput = "Pretty much as the title says. Your challenge is to build " + selectedKind + ". Good Luck!"
                break;
            case 'Jigsaw Challenge':
                miniGeneratorOutput = generateJigsawHouse();
                break;
            case "No Mistakes":
                miniGeneratorOutput = noMistakes();
                break;
            case "Each Room A Different Pack":
                miniGeneratorOutput = generateCertainPacks();
                break;
    
            // Add cases for other challenges here if needed
            default:
                miniGeneratorOutput = 'This challenge does not have a mini-generator.';
        }
    
        // Display the mini-generator output
        document.getElementById('sim-build').innerHTML += miniGeneratorOutput; }
    
            // Mini-generator function for Certain Budget challenge
            function generateCertainBudget() {
                var output = 'Every room in this house has a budget. There are ';
                var numBedrooms = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1; // Generate 1-3 bedrooms
                var numBathrooms = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1; // Generate 1-2 bathrooms
                var isCombinedKitchen = Math.random() < 0.5; // Randomly decide if kitchen is combined
                var extras = ['study', 'nursery', 'garden', 'pantry'];
                var livingRoomBudget = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 5000; // Generate budget for living room
    
                // Generate budget for each bedroom and bathroom
                var bedroomBudgets = [];
                var bathroomBudgets = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < numBedrooms; i++) {
                    var minBudget = i * 4000 + 5000;
                    var maxBudget = i * 5000 + 15000;
                    var bedroomBudget = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxBudget - minBudget + 1)) + minBudget;
                    bedroomBudgets.push(bedroomBudget);
                }
                for (var j = 0; j < numBathrooms; j++) {
                    var bathroomBudget = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 2000;
                    bathroomBudgets.push(bathroomBudget);
                }
    
                // Construct the output string
                output += numBedrooms + ' bedrooms with budgets of ';
                output += bedroomBudgets.join(', ') + ' respectively. <br><br> ';
                output += numBathrooms + ' bathrooms with budgets of ';
                output += bathroomBudgets.join(', ') + ' respectively. <br><br> ';
    
                if (isCombinedKitchen) {
                    output += 'a combined kitchen and dining room with a budget of ';
                    var kitchenBudget = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 5000; // Generate budget for combined kitchen
                    output += kitchenBudget + '<br><br>';
                } else {
                    output += 'a kitchen and a dining room, each with budgets of ';
                    var kitchenBudget = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 5000; // Generate budget for kitchen
                    var diningRoomBudget = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 5000; // Generate budget for dining room
                    output += kitchenBudget + ' for the kitchen and ' + diningRoomBudget + ' for the dining room <br><br>';
                }
                
                output += 'a living room with a budget of ' + livingRoomBudget + '.<br><br> and ';
    
                // Add extras
                var extrasOutput = '';
                for (var k = 0; k < extras.length; k++) {
                    if (Math.random() < 0.5) { // 50% chance of including each extra
                        var extra = extras[k];
                        var extraBudget = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 5000; // Generate budget for extra
                        extrasOutput += 'a ' + extra + ' with a budget of ' + extraBudget + ', ';
                    }
                }
                if (extrasOutput !== '') {
                    output += extrasOutput.substring(0, extrasOutput.length - 2); // Remove trailing comma and space
                } else {
                    output += 'no additional rooms.';
                }
    
                return output;
            }
    
    function generateCertainColour() {
        var output = 'Every room in this house has a certain colour scheme. There are ';
        var numBedrooms = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1; // Generate 1-3 bedrooms
        var numBathrooms = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1; // Generate 1-2 bathrooms
        var isCombinedKitchen = Math.random() < 0.5; // Randomly decide if kitchen is combined
        var extras = ['study', 'nursery', 'garden', 'pantry'];
        var livingRoomColour = getRandomColour(); // Generate colour for living room
    
        // Generate colours for each bedroom and bathroom
        var bedroomColours = [];
        var bathroomColours = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < numBedrooms; i++) {
            var bedroomColour = getRandomColour();
            bedroomColours.push(bedroomColour);
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < numBathrooms; j++) {
            var bathroomColour = getRandomColour();
            bathroomColours.push(bathroomColour);
        }
    
        // Construct the output string
        output += numBedrooms + ' bedrooms with colours of ';
        output += bedroomColours.join(', ') + ' respectively. <br><br> ';
        output += numBathrooms + ' bathrooms with colours of ';
        output += bathroomColours.join(', ') + ' respectively. <br><br> ';
    
        if (isCombinedKitchen) {
            output += 'a combined kitchen and dining room with a colour scheme of ';
            var kitchenColour = getRandomColour(); // Generate colour for combined kitchen
            output += kitchenColour + '<br><br>';
        } else {
            output += 'a kitchen and a dining room, each with colour schemes of ';
            var kitchenColour = getRandomColour(); // Generate colour for kitchen
            var diningRoomColour = getRandomColour(); // Generate colour for dining room
            output += kitchenColour + ' for the kitchen and ' + diningRoomColour + ' for the dining room <br><br>';
        }
        
        output += 'a living room with a colour scheme of ' + livingRoomColour + '.<br><br> and ';
    
        // Add extras
        var extrasOutput = '';
        for (var k = 0; k < extras.length; k++) {
            if (Math.random() < 0.5) { // 50% chance of including each extra
                var extra = extras[k];
                var extraColour = getRandomColour(); // Generate colour for extra room
                extrasOutput += 'a ' + extra + ' with a colour scheme of ' + extraColour + ', ';
            }
        }
        if (extrasOutput !== '') {
            output += extrasOutput.substring(0, extrasOutput.length - 2); // Remove trailing comma and space
        } else {
            output += 'no additional rooms.';
        }
    
        return output;
    }
    
    // Function to generate a random colour from the list of colours
    function getRandomColour() {
        var colours = ['blue', 'red', 'pink', 'green', 'yellow', 'white', 'black', 'grey', 'orange', 'purple', 'brown'];
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
        return colours[randomIndex];
    }
     
    function timedHouseChallenge() {
        var numBedrooms = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1; // Generate 1-3 bedrooms
        var numToilets = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1; // Generate 1-2 toilets
    
        var combinedLivingRoomKitchen = Math.random() < 0.5; // Randomly decide if living room and kitchen are combined
    
        var extraFeatures = ['patio', 'pantry', 'study', 'gym'];
        var selectedFeatures = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < extraFeatures.length; i++) {
            if (Math.random() < 0.5) { // 50% chance of including each extra feature
                selectedFeatures.push(extraFeatures[i]);
            }
        }
    
        // Construct the output string
        var output = 'It should have ' + numBedrooms + ' bedroom(s) and ' + numToilets + ' toilet(s).';
    
        if (combinedLivingRoomKitchen) {
            output += ' The living room and kitchen are combined.';
        } else {
            output += ' There is a separate living room and kitchen.';
        }
    
        if (selectedFeatures.length > 0) {
            output += ' Additional features include: ' + selectedFeatures.join(', ') + '.';
        } else {
            output += ' No additional features are included.';
        }
    
        return output;
    }
    
    function generateHouseDetails() {
        // Randomly determine the number of bedrooms (1-3)
        const numBedrooms = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    
        // Randomly determine the number of bathrooms (1-2)
        const numBathrooms = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    
        // Randomly determine if the kitchen and living room are combined or separate
        const isCombinedKitchenLiving = Math.random() < 0.5;
    
        // Randomly determine the number of extra rooms (0-2)
        const numExtraRooms = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    
        // Array of possible extra rooms
        const extraRooms = ['a study', 'a nursery', 'a patio', 'a conservatory', 'a greenhouse', 'a gym', 'a playroom', 'a studio'];
    
        // Shuffle the extra rooms array
        for (let i = extraRooms.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            [extraRooms[i], extraRooms[j]] = [extraRooms[j], extraRooms[i]];
        }
    
        // Select the first numExtraRooms rooms from the shuffled array
        const selectedExtraRooms = extraRooms.slice(0, numExtraRooms);
    
        // Return an object with all the generated details
        return {
            numBedrooms,
            numBathrooms,
            isCombinedKitchenLiving,
            numExtraRooms,
            selectedExtraRooms
        };
    }
    

`
tried enqueuing it from functions.php, calling it from a script file and linking the source. Doesn't seem to work

I haven't looked closely at your problem, but I just want to offer this: PHP and Javascript run at different times. PHP runs on the server, whereas Javascript runs when the page gets to the user's browser. If this isn't helpful, let me know and I'll delete this comment okay?

what does the rendered page source look like? are there any console messages?

@ThisGuy I've added the webpage link for you to look at. I have managed to get the ticks to work on Select All (only thing set up right now) but not the generator for the button.

when you inspect the source for your page, inside the browser, how are your script tags rendered?  is the path to your script files correct?  you are able to load your js file directly into a browser for reading, using the url. so the url needs to be correct. is it?

@ThisGuy it comes up with a  404 when I go to https://littleseabear.com/website_1be365e3/wp-content/themes/type-child2022/challengeGenerator.js the JS code is there

If you look at the browser's developer console, there's a syntax error in both VM19_challengeGenerator.js and challengeGenerator.js on line 16. Then script.js can't read properties of null when reading addEventListener because there is no id of mobile-sidebar-overlay

@aynber just tried renaming the file as the console seemed to be showing an old version but the error. Is the mobile-sidebar issue an issue for the parent theme as I haven't coded anything for mobile thanks

Are you shure that "get_stylesheet_directory_uri" gets the right path of your js scripts?
You get a 404 for challengeGenerator.js, when a js script fails or is not found the dependants sometimes are not even being call due to the error.

challenge-generator.js:16:5 has the same error, challengeGenerator.js:569:5 is the same error at a different line. Get yourself a good editor with error checking that will help debug the scripts, and pay attention to the browser's developer console as it will give you some good information.
